# scheduled task only running when ran manually besides it's automated

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-task-scheduler

So...

I have an automated Windows Task Scheduler Task rolled out via a GPO.
That task is running the powershell which receives a script to run via the -File Parameter (file path on our storage server) (we are not using visual basic and we will not).
The script is supposed to create a local outlook signature and set that one as the standard one, aswell as save the signature files (.htm, .txt, .rtf) on a designated file-path (we use those files for another task on our exchange server to set the OWA signatures).

The task is set as "Run when user log-on" and "Run with highest privileges". "Error-Code" is "0x0" but the "Last Runtime" is not shortly after log-on.

So when looking in that folder I'm supposed to see some files of different users, for example my colleague ones from today, as he has signed on to his computer some hours ago, but the files in the folder are days old, aswell as my own, which is NOT supposed to be like that.

However when I start Windows Task Scheduler as a non-administrator and run the task manually it still runs as before, but now also updates the files in the folder and everything looks like it's supposed to be.

What am I doing wrong? I need the tasks to be running properly and fully automated.

Comment: Are you sure network is available at the script execution time? If offline login is allowed respectively "wait for network" is not set the script may be executed before the path to the network share is available, if the system has been rebooted or switched on right before login.

Comment: Great idea, ill try out to make task scheduler wait for network

Comment: @Robert so I've just tested that out, still does not work. The Task History in the Task Scheduler still only shows "Task registration" on logon, but nothing else, no "Task triggered", "Action started" whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

Because I rolled out the scheduled Task via GPO I had to change from "Action" -> "Update" to "Action" -> "Create". Now the task and it's powershell script run perfectly fine after user logon.